# "match authors" (feature) only works before/during `Github Import` not after the fact? Can you change to original "commit name" and back?

Tags: authentication, github, import

https://docs.github.com/en/github/importing-your-projects-to-github/updating-commit-author-attribution-with-github-importer says it works beforehand, but what if I wait after doing https://github.com/new/import, will https://github.com/painingattention/realityl/import/authors still work?

I am torn between keeping my original "commit name" (from urgency of https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-articles/What-to-do-with-your-Mercurial-repos-when-Bitbucket-sunsets/ba-p/1155380/page/20 I am rushing), and or letting Github do any scary fuzzy hidden automated magic coding.

Also, can you change to original "commit name" association and back or will that (ever) give an error?

Is (before or after) the orginal name's formatting intact/preserved in the history log (are "match author" changes/automations directly attributed/recorded as their own Git entry, or is that a repository or U.I. behavior change, userside or serverside issue?)?

(The personal perspective is that I wrote unique commit names and noticed the "match" conversion maybe hid that artifact, is my original naming at the time committed still saved or hidden as a conversion artifact?)

Comment: "If the author's email address is not associated with their GitHub account, they can add the address to their account after the import, and the commits will be correctly attributed." (quoted from https://docs.github.com/en/github/importing-your-projects-to-github/updating-commit-author-attribution-with-github-importer) does not fully explain what and where data will change. Is that effecting/changing the repo or just server-side site settings?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "no, it won't work"... but the long answer is:

First of all, there are two different kinds of author mapping done by GitHub:

1. At import time, your commits are not actually mapped to a GitHub account – they are only mapped to the "full name <email>" taken *from* the user's GitHub profile.

   This author mapping **cannot** be easily changed later. Author information is embedded directly in the generated Git commits, and once a commit is made it is generally considered immutable. That's why this feature [only works](https://docs.github.com/en/github/importing-your-projects-to-github/about-github-importer) when importing *non-Git* repositories – it is actually part of format conversion process and can only be done while generating the Git commits, not afterwards.
2. At display time, whenever GitHub needs to show a link to a user profile, it will do so according to *only* the email address that's stored in the Git commit. (There's no additional magic at this step, it's always email address-based.)

   No matter what actual author name is stored within the Git commit, GitHub will simply **ignore** it and will show the name from your GitHub profile instead.

Overall, this means the author names do not need to match GitHub accounts, only email addresses do. So if your original Hg repository already has correct author addresses, you do not need to apply any import-time mapping at all.

(I am assuming your original repository was in Hg format, because if it were in Git format then the importer wouldn't offer remapping at all – it would just grab an exact copy of the repository and that's it.)

---

My recommendation here would be:

1. Use `hg log` to check what email address is stored in your original commits, and make sure the same address is added to your GitHub profile.
2. Allow GitHub's importer tool to do the thing, but **do not** apply any author mapping at all, just allow it to keep whatever it found.
3. Download the repository using `git clone`, then use `git log --format=fuller` inspect the full name and email address stored in the resulting Git commits.
4. If the import produced poor results, or if the original commits contained garbage email addresses, this can be fixed by rebuilding the repository and using `git push --force` to upload the "fixed" version. (This is similar to Hg 'stripping' all commits out of the repository.)

Although I said the authorship of Git commits cannot be easily changed, there *are* nevertheless ways to change it – it only requires rewriting the whole repository. Two common tools for doing so are `git filter-repo` and the older `git filter-branch`. Or you could even re-do the import from Hg using completely different tools, e.g. using [git-remote-hg](https://pypi.org/project/git-remote-hg/). (This can be done even after BitBucket goes down completely; all you need is a local Hg clone.)

As every such rewrite changes all your commit IDs, you should only do this when your Git repository is still new (i.e. people haven't really begun using it).

Comment: Is, before or after, the orginal name's formatting intact? That's what I was thinking reading your answer to my question. [Otherwise I think you're correct, kind of hoping for a second opinion before I vote, I really have not tested and do not exactly know the repository vs UI behavior.]

Comment: The personal perspective is that I wrote unique commit names and noticed the "match" conversion maybe hid that artifact, is my original naming at the time committed still saved or hidden as a conversion artifact?